# GCM response results has more items than request registration_ids

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

We send such payload into GCM server

```
{"data":{"title":"Unlimited Music Ringtones for 24hrs!","p":"5;"},"registration_ids":["APA91bF2U2KaLF173wyqUWfyxKw_xJI4fW22MKRUuoG3E6uubO-a4F9_SS0byscd5YwbbQZsgCsuxmI_IYINZOGRonMH64hZrhDqeqa0a5ixrnhPvcLGGIrIm-J624TCwZFtVktPypyr"],"time_to_live":43200}
```

But in response we get 9 result items

```
{"multicast_id":6634278235585666161,"success":1,"failure":8,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1443085201594600%341e1321f9fd7ecd"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Issue reproduced from time to time. This is undefined behaviour? How to determine which response it corresponding to register_id?
P.S. We used persistent connection

Comment: Are you using the latest GCM version which uses InstanceID? Does this only happen when you send to `registration_ids`, and not when using `to`?

Comment: Now we not using InstanceId. Yep, this reproduced only when we send request with `registration_ids` without `to`

Comment: Ah I see. It's going to be hard to find a solution to this with a deprecated way of registering. I suggest using the latest, and if the issue persists, report the issue on the GCM [issues list](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues) on GitHub.